# Same origin policy by default

Tags: html, css, web, same-origin-policy

If I have a `<img>` tag and with src of another origin, will it be blocked by the same-origin policy by default

Comment: No: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy#cross-origin_network_access

Comment: @jub0bs ok. What about xmlhttprequest with different url?

Comment: See the duplicate, in particular the section headed "Why you can display data in the page without reading it with JS".